# Convert an ascii file column in integer

Tags: c++, perl, awk, grep, integer

I have a file with two columns, separated by space. The first column is integer but the second is double. My file has the following format

```
1 201.45
2 201.42
3 202.92

...
```

What I want to do is print the same file with two integer columns. The new file should like that

```
1 201
2 201
3 203

...
```

I tried to do using awk giving the following command

```
awk '{print $1 " " (int) $2}' file.dat
```

but as expected it's not working.

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: I take it you want rounding, otherwise I'd suggest `sed 's/\..*//g'`

Comment: @Sobrique : Thank you very much for your comment! Well rounding should work!

Comment: ***C++*** AND ***Perl*** AND ***awk***??? Pick a language, please.

Comment: @SinanÜnür : I just tagged all those language because maybe it could be an easier task in a different ;anguage since they are more or less the same...

Comment: s/more or less the same/based on similar syntax but vastly different in practical use/ :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literally just need to add 0.5

```
awk '{print $1,int($2+0.5)}' file.dat
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The trick was to use `int($2)` instead of `(int) $2` as you would do in `c++` . Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Thanos `(int)$2` in C++ would be a cast. There is **no** casting in awk. `int()` is a function. awk is a very stripped down C-like language with a few bells and whistles for text processing. DO not assume that what you can do in C/C++ you can also do in awk or vice-versa. Learn it like it's a new language from the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: @EdMorton true it is more like the `trunc()` function in c++.

Answer (score 1):

How about perl:

```
perl -lne "print join ( ' ', map { int $_ + 0.5 } split);" file.dat
```

Gives:

```
1 201
2 201
3 203
```

NB: trick is - add `0.5` because `int` rounds down, and so this gives the desired result.